# Change color of primefaces schedule event for current date

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How to change color of primefaces schedule event for current date ? Please provide CSS...

I am using primefaces(3.5) schedule component.

Comment: The date of today seems to acquire `fc-day fc-fri ui-widget-content fc-today ui-state-highlight` classes. Play with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.fc-today  /* today */
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #44565F, #0077b3) !important;
}
```

I had the same problem. I have tested this on chrome and its working. Change the colors as per your choice